# Linux - Remove packages whose name include special string

Tags: linux, yum

I want to remove packages with name including "texlive". However, when I use "texlive*" directly as below, it's no use. So, what should I do?

```
atlas@localhost /> sudo yum autoremove texlive*
fish: No matches for wildcard 'texlive*'.
```

Comment: Not a programning question... These questions belong to [Superuser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: Have you tried sudo yum autoremove "texlive*"?

Comment: @RobertRossmann Sorry, I will take care of it next time :)